# restricting the genes in the Genetic Algorithm chromosome to integral multiples

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

If i am using the GA from matlab, is there a way to restrict the genes in the chromosome to integral multiples of say 10000?

I have a chromosome like this `{Pdg1 Pdg2 ... Pdg33}`, I need `0<=Pdgn<=400000` where `n=1,2..,33` and `mod(Pdgn ,10000)=0`. Does the GA,(the multiobjective optimization one) in matlab allow that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gamultiobj` does not support integer constraints. I usually perform a scalarization and use plain `ga`.

```
function res = scalarizedFitness(x)
    [obj1, obj2, obj3] = yourFitnessFunction(x);
    %choose w1, w2, w3
    res = w1 * obj1 + w2 * obj2 + w3 * obj3;
end
```

The way to avoid scalarization is to write your own mutation functions for `gamultiobj`. I never did so. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-10PDHC/) are some notes about it.

Integer constraints are supported by `ga` since some version. My 2011b supports it. Type `help ga` and find if it contains the line `X = ga(FITNESSFCN,NVARS,A,b,[],[],lb,ub,NONLCON,INTCON)`. Note that `INTCON` parameter which is used to say what parameters are to be integer.

`0<=Pdgn<=400000` : You can set lower and upper bound by using `lb` and `ub` parameters.

`mod(Pdgn ,10000)=0` There are different ways to put complicated constraints. I guess the most optimal for you is to change your fitness function:

From `f(Pdgn) where 0<=Pdgn<40000` to `f(X) where 0<X<40 and Pdgn = X * 10000`

The resulting code may look like

```
function result = fitnessfun(X)
    Pgds = X * 10000;
    result = scalarizedFitness(Pgds);
end

NVARS = 33;
%lower bounds
lb = 0 * ones(1, NVARS);
%upper bounds
ub = 40 * ones(1, NVARS);
%which variables are integers (all of them)
intcon = 1:NVARS;
result = ga(@fintessfun, NVARS, [], [], [], [], lb, ub, [], intcon);
```